# Not able to get Asset Level field permission through SOQL

Tags: soql, ant, permission-sets, field-level-security

I have a permission set named **abc**.

Permission to *Asset Level* field for **Asset** object is defined like below in **abc**:

[image]

I am trying to get field level permissions for abc permission set using the below query:

```
SELECT Name,
            (
                SELECT
                    SObjectType,
                    Field,
                    PermissionsRead,
                    PermissionsEdit
                FROM FieldPerms
                WHERE SObjectType='Asset'
            )
        FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name='abc'
```

But in the results, I am not able to get *Asset Level* and some other field permissions.

I tried fetching the permission set using **ANT** but not able to get permission for the above field there too.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Consider using the SFDX CLI with a command like `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m PermissionSet` and see if you can see the metadata permissions there

Comment: Are you executing the SOQL as an admin and in which API version ? I've created a permission set `abc` in a dev org, tried SOQL under API 47 and got result for Asset level field permission. SOQL result shows field as `Asset.AssetLevel`

Comment: @Shamina Thanks. I logged in with my System Administrator account and able to see this field.
But facing similar kind of situation with __CurrencyIsoCode__ in **Account**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to recap:
Ensure that the user executing the SOQL has relevant permission on the object and fields you are trying to query from FieldPermissions.

Regarding your question about **CurrencyIsoCode**:

As per chapter "Special Properties for Field Permissions" in documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm), fields that are always readable and/or writable, don’t return a `FieldPermissions` record.

Although `CurrencyIsoCode` field is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, if multiple currencies is enabled in the org, `CurrencyIsoCode` becomes a universally required field and hence always readable irrespective of the profile or permission set.
This is why this field is not returned when querying on FieldPermissions.