# Get all field level permission from SOQL for an permission set

Tags: soql, permission-sets, fls

**What I want to do:**

I am trying to create a tool in Java, which query permission sets from Salesforce Org using REST(As we do in workbench).

After getting all the permission sets which field permissions, I want generate an excel workbook which will have all permission sets with all objects with fls.

**Where I am:**
I am able to query permissions sets with fls and able to generate excel workbook.

**My apporach:**
I have a permission set **abc**.

This permission set has below permission for *Account* object fields:

[image]

I run below **SOQL** to get field permission for the permission set:

```
SELECT Parent.Name,Field,PermissionsRead,PermissionsEdit 

FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SObjectType IN ('Account') AND Parent.Name IN ('abc')
```

But I get results like below:

[image]

I am expecting result like below:

[image]

How can I get all field permissions using SOQL?

Comment: Removing the where clause should give you all the field permissions related to all objects: `SELECT Parent.Name,SObjectType, Field,PermissionsRead,PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions `

Comment: Tried this.
This starts getting all fields permissions' for all permission sets. The number is around 300K.
I just need permission for all fields of single object, single permission set.

Comment: Export the result to Excel and then filter out the records.

Comment: I have started the CSV export 30 minutes ago. Still not completed.

Comment: You can filter out the records in SOQL for a single object and then take the extract.

Comment: Tried filter on **SobjectType** but the results don't have any row with read permission as **false**

Comment: Seems to me that this is logical; you only need an entry in the DB if there is some permission and where you have no entry in the DB you clearly have no permission. To have them all, rather than just those entries necessary, would be inefficient.

Comment: @PhilW We also don't get the permission of the fields which have default permissions by SOQL. Refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288437/not-able-to-get-asset-level-field-permission-through-soql). How would I know that field have __No Access__ or __default permission__?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by @benahm, SOQL on FieldPermissions retrieves only enabled field permissions for the permission set.

Furthermore, as per chapter "Special Properties for Field Permissions" in documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm), fields that are always readable and/or writable, don’t return a FieldPermissions record.

Note that getDescribe methods can also be accessed via REST API, refer to this [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm)

For example you can do a GET call to this endpoint to retrieve list of fields for Asset object: `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Asset/describe/`

From the response, `fields` list provides several attributes on each field, more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

Note: The name of the attributes are different when getDescribe is called from API compared to via APEX, for 
e.g `isNillable()` becomes `nillable` for API result

So compare `fields` list attributes from getDescribe response with SOQL result on FieldPermissions.

If a field has **nillable = false and permissionable = false** but **does not appear** in SOQL on FieldPermissions, it means that field cannot be empty but we cannot assign FLS to it, then the field is always readable (e.g Id field wont appear on FieldPermissions result but **PermissionRead is true**)

If a field has **nillable = true and permissionable = true** but **does not appear** in SOQL on FieldPermissions, then we can deduce that **PermissionRead and PermissionEdit is false**

If a field has **nillable = true and permissionable = true** and **appears** in SOQL on FieldPermissions, then retrieve PermissionRead and PermissionEdit from FieldPermissions SOQL

If a field has **nillable = true and permissionable = false** and **does not appear** in SOQL on FieldPermission, then consider **PermissionRead is true** because it can be another type of field which is always readable e.g. CurrencyISOCode which can always have default currency field

For missing field from SOQL on FieldPermissions, also check the field attribute **updateable** from getDescribe response, to determine if field can have true or false for PermissionEdit .

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the [SOAP API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm)

> FieldPermissions : Represents the **enabled** field permissions for
>   the parent PermissionSet. This object is available in API version 24.0
>   and later.

So when querying the `FieldPermissions` object you'll only get the enabled permissions

#### Possible solution

1- You should query the list of all fields of an SObject with another mean, example [using Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/apex-dynamically-get-fields-for-an-sobject-no-hardcoding)

2- Query the `FieldPermissions` for a given permission set, then all the fields that are not listed in the result, are by default hidden in the FLS